# how to set value of a table cell to null?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function addRow(billingTable) 
{

    var table = document.getElementById(billingTable);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) 
    {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML; 

// after this line the new cell is created but it also copies the
// value from the 1st row of the table.How can I set the value of
// this new cell to null or blank string ??


        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) 
        {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this line,

```
newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
```

You may simply write,

```
newcell.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: try writing this, **newcell.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";**

Comment: this creates a much bigger cells with value as "NEW CELL" .
I need blank cells where I can write values !!

Comment: try writing this, **newcell.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";**

Comment: table are never editable. you might have added text box(<input />) to make it editable. if so then put the input tag in between "".

Comment: below is my table code...how can I put it in the javascript function ?

Comment: <td>
    <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="Position" name="Position" value="" style="width: 139px" maxlength="74" onchange="toUpperCase()"/>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="Amount" name="Amount" value="0" style="width: 139px" onchange="checkNumber(); calc();"/>
    </td>

Comment: <td>
    <input type="text" id="Price" name="Price" value="0" style="width: 139px" onchange="checkNumber(); calc();"/>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="Sum" name="Sum" value="" style="width: 139px"/>
    </td>
   </tr>

Comment: you may add like this, **newcell.innerHTML = "<INPUT type=\"checkbox\" name=\"chk\"/>";** and as all input tags have different attribute values, so need to write it indivisually. loop will not work for setting innerHTML.

Comment: you welcome, hope you will not mind to upvote this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The new cell is created by the line

```
var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
```

If you want the new cell not to have the same contents as another cell, then don't assign it's `innerHTML` to another cell's `innerHTML`. Just leave it blank.

Comment: if I leave it blank. a new cell is created but it is as thin as a line  !!

Comment: Then give it a style. Set a width or height.